# How do I test whether a Django response was generated by a particular view?

Tags: django, testing

In writing unit tests for Django, how would I test whether a particular view was used in rendering a URL? I was hoping there would exist TestCase.assertViewUsed, but I can't see it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` to create an url from view. This way you will see, whether view is mapped properly to an address.